# clojure filter nested map to return keys based on inner map values

Tags: dictionary, clojure

For this nested map called "tables",

```
  (def tables 
   {:tableA {:occupied false :party nil} 
    :tableB {:occupied true :party nil}
    :tableC {:occupied false :party nil}})
```

how do I filter and get back the keys where :occupied = false ?

correct result should be `(:tableA :tableC)`

can I do this with "filter" HOF? Should I be using a list comprehension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it pretty easily with `keep`:

```
(keep (fn [[k v]] (if-not (:occupied v) k)) tables)
```

However, as you observed, using `for` is often a good solution whenever you're mapping / filtering sequences, especially if you're dealing with nested sequences.

```
(for [[k v] tables :when (not (:occupied v))] k)
```

I usually prefer using `for`, especially when I want to use destructuring on the target items. In this case, destructuring is nice for binding the key/value pair with `[k v]`.

Comment: thank you! I thought I could use for, but could not figure out the correct syntax to make it actually work.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what your use case is, but can I suggest structuring your data as a set of maps? Sets have certain properties that allow you to query them using relational algebra similar to the way you query tables in SQL. The clojure.set/select function is similar to a WHERE in SQL.

```
(use 'clojure.set)

(def tables
    #{{:table "A" :occupied false :party nil} 
      {:table "B" :occupied true :party nil}
      {:table "C" :occupied false :party nil}})

(select #(= false (:occupied %)) tables)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks, I'm going to consider this. I have not figured out yet if I want a set of maps, or a map of maps, of a vector of maps...I'm still pretty new to clojure.  A set of maps may be what I need.